# how to install a c package systemwide and translating CMake to a makefile

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

I am trying to use a c package I found on github to use in another project: [GattLibb](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib)

It uses cmake to build the project. However, the project I am working on uses a Makefile.

How do I go about installing the GattLib project such that I can build the example files using `gcc`?

I have tried the following to be able to include `glib.h` and `glibconfig.h`:

`gcc read_write_memory.c -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include`

Which results in undefined references errors

Comment: It's a library. You first build it as is, and then you link it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I had to read the readme more carefully....
Her are the steps I took to install the library:

- `$ sudo apt install rpm bluez libbluetooth-dev doxygen libglib2.0-dev`
- `$ git clone git@github.com:labapart/gattlib.git`
- `$ cd gattlib`
- `$ mkdir build && cd build`
- `$ cmake ..`
- `$ make`
- `$ cpack ..`
- `$ sudo apt install ./gattlib_0.3-dev_x86_64.deb`

Don't download the provided `.deb` files from their github page, as these require specific (older) python versions

Finally compile with:
`gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include <file.c> -o <out_name> lglib-2.0 -lgattlib -lpthread`